# I am new in programming. I keep getting an error message after compiling my code that contains a class definition included in a .h file

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a member function of a custom class, but I keep getting error messages:

```
expected primary-expression before First_name 
expected primary-expression before Middle_name 
expected primary-expression before Surname
```

This is the code for `main cpp`:

```
#include <iostream >
#include <People.h>
auto NAME = P.Name_Input( std:string First_name, std::string Middle_name, std::string Surname) ;
std::cout<<NAME<<std::endl;
```

This is the header file:

```
class Person{
   public:
   std::string Name_Input(std::string First_name, std::string Middle_name, std::string Surname);
} ;
```

The header file compiles well, and has been link to a `.cpp` file to define the method, and that section also works perfectly. My problem is with the `main.cpp` file.

Comment: You forgot to include the definition for `std::string`. It is in the header `<string>`.

Comment: IMHO, you should use ".hpp" or ".hxx" for C++ header files.  The ".h" usually indicates a C language file.  For example, header files with `class` are not compatible with the C language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is not bad advice, however having `.h` for C++ header is not that uncommon.

Comment: 1. `#include <iostream >` is not in the standard header and it should be `#include <iostream>` without space. 2. Adding `std::string` (not `(std::string)`) before variables in function call is invalid. 3. `std::cout<<NAME<<std::endl;` must be inside function definition.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `main.cpp` nor `People.h` are defining `std::string`, so the compiler doesn't know what it is.

You need to add `#include <string>` to `People.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef People_H
#define People_H

#include <string> // <-- add this

class Person{
   public:
      std::string Name_Input(std::string First_name, std::string Middle_name, std::string Surname);
};

#endif
```

A general rule of thumb is that *any* source file that needs to use a type defined in another source file should `#include` that other file (except in cases where using forward declarations will suffice, such as when breaking circular references).  See [Is it good practice to rely on headers being included transitively?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262019/).  Which means that `main.cpp` should have an `#include <string>` statement as well, even if `People.h` (or any other header `main.cpp` uses) already has its own `#include <string>` statement.

Also, your use of `std::string` in `main()` is all wrong.  Don't include the type name when passing a variable to a function or class method.  Use the type name only in the *declaration* of a variable or function parameter.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // <-- add this
#include "People.h"

int main()
{
    Person P;
    std::string First_name;
    std::string Middle_name;
    std::string Surname;

    ...

    auto NAME = P.Name_Input(First_name, Middle_name, Surname);
    std::cout << NAME << std::endl;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```